# use shell variable when calling sys function

Tags: shell, variables

my system is Ubuntu 10

**here is my code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
pid = `ps -ef | grep process_string | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}'`
`kill -9 $pid`
```

**pid** is the process id of process_string(there is only one matched)

but when I run this sh,I don't kill the process

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't have space on either side of the assignment. In this case it's trying to execute `pid` with arguments of `=` and the stdout of `ps -ef ...`.
2. The second line will try to execute the output of `kill -9 $pid`, you don't want that.
3. Better to use `$(...)` than backticks.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 pid=$(ps -ef | grep process_string | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}')
 kill -9 $pid
```

You may want to use `pgrep` to get the pid instead, or `pkill` or `killall` to just kill by name directly (be careful with that last one, as the name implies it will kill *all* instances of the named program).

Comment: thx~ it works.is that any sys commond can be called in shell script directly?and what's the usage of the symbol **``**?

Comment: Backticks and `$(...)` are functionally identical, the `$(...)` form just handles things like quoting (much) better, and can be shown properly in markdown. They are used to capture output, e.g. to assign it to a variable or to put it on the command line directly (`kill -9 $(pgrep process_string)`).

Comment: I'll check **pkill** and **killall** you mentioned later.thank you 凯文! :)